# faliure in reading training data: tagger.cpp (393) CRF++

Tags: c++, crf++

While I am running CRF++ on my training data (train.txt) I have got the follwoing error

```
C:\Users\2012\Desktop\CRF_Software_Package\CRF++-0.58>crf_learn template train.d
ata model
CRF++: Yet Another CRF Tool Kit
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Taku Kudo, All rights reserved.

reading training data: tagger.cpp(393) [feature_index_->buildFeatures(this)]
0.00 s
```

My training data contains Unicode characters and the data is saved using Notepad (encoding= Unicode big indian)

I am not sure If the problem with the template or with the format of the training data. How can I check the format of the training data?

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was? I get the same and my template_file only contains `U01:%x[0,1]`, can you point me to the solution, please?

Comment: You need only to change the encoding of the file containing the training set. Try using UTF-8.

Comment: @Wahedsaw I changed the encoding to UTF-8, still the same error. Any other solutions you're aware of?

Comment: @cerr your problem might be different. [0,1] might be referring to the column where labels are stored, and you cannot do this!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because of your template file.
Please check whether you have included the last column which is gold-standard as training features. The column index starts from 0.
E.g if you have 6 column in your BIO file.
The template should not have something like %x[0,5]

Comment: I think I'm having similar issue [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792024/define-crf-template-file-for-conll-shared-task-evaluation-script) do you know how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with the Template file 
check your features for incorrect "grammer"
i.e
U10:%x[-1,0]/% [0,0]

you realize that after the second % there is a missing 'x'
the corrected line should look like the one below
U10:%x[-1,0]/%x[0,0]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, files are in UTF-8, and template file and training file are definitely in the correct format. The reason was that CRFPP expects at most 1024 columns in the input files. Would be great if it would output an appropriate error message in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the Unicode encoding, but the template file.

Have a look at this similar Q: [The failure in using CRF+0.58 train NE Model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43487195/2238884)