# define CRF++ template file

Tags: c++, perl, nlp

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886251/faliure-in-reading-training-data-tagger-cpp-393-crf) is my issue, but it doesn't say HOW to define the template file correctly.

My training file looks like this:

```
上   B-NR
海   L-NR
浦   B-NR
东   L-NR
开   B-NN
发   L-NN
与   U-CC
法   B-NN
制   L-NN
建   B-NN
...
```

Comment: Was your problem solved ?

Comment: yeah, I just had to look closer at the documentation- as lame an answer as that is. I mean, when people tell me that- usually i'm pretty... displeased. but anyway- thats the truth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRF++ is extremely easy to use. The instructions on the website explains it clearly.

http://crfpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html

Suppose we extract feature for the line
东   L-NR

Unigram

> U02:%x[0,0] #means column 0 of the current line
>
> U03:%x[1,0] #means column 0 of the next line

So the underlying feature is "column0=开"

Similar for bigrams

Comment: what do you mean the underlying feature is 开? aren't we considering 东? I want to know what is the POS of 东. What do you mean by 'similar for bigrams', would you please show me an example?

Comment: when you are classifying current word "东", you not just take it as a feature but also can take surrounding words. That's why the index %x[1,0] means the next word and %x[-1,0] means the previous word.

Comment: bigram is just conjunction of two words. e.g. the previous two words

Comment: I'm at SUTD, are you also in Singapore?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue arises from not clearly understanding how CRF++ is processing the training file.  Your features may not include the values in the last column.  These are the labels!  If you were to include them in your features, your model would be trivially perfect!  When you define your template file, because you only have two columns, it can only include rules of the form %x[n,0].  It is hardcoded into CRF++ (though not clearly documented, as far as I can tell), that -4 <= n <= 4.