# The failure in using CRF+0.58 train NE Model

Tags: linux, nlp, crf++

### when i use CRF++0.58 to model a NE and progarm have a problem:

#### "reading training data:tagger.cpp(399) [feature_index_->buildFeatures(this)] 0.00s"

1. the develop environment:

   - red hat linux 6.5,gcc 5.0,CRF++0.58
2. written feature template:

   - template
3. dataset:

   - Boson_train.txt
   - Boson_test.txt
   - the first column is words ,the second column is pos,the third column is NER tagger
4. the problem:

   - when i want to train the NER model, i type this sentences "crf_learn -f 3 -c 4.0 template Boson_train crf_model", and i got
     this notification, "reading training data:tagger.cpp(399) [feature_index_->buildFeatures(this)] 0.00s". I can't understand
     the C++ language, so i can't fix the problem.
5. the method i tryed:

   - 1.change the encode type of dataset. I use notepad++ to change "utf-8 with no BOM" to "utf-8". It didn't work.
   - 2.change the delimiter from '\t' to ' '(space). It didn't work.
   - 3.And i think maybe the template was wrong.So i use the crf++0.58/example/seg/template for test. It worked. But this template
       is simple, so I use /example/JapaneseNE/template which is more similar with my feature template. It didn't  work. Then， i check
       the JapaneseNE example It works well. So i got confused. Is there someone can help me.
6. template

   - U00:%x[-2,0]
   - U01:%x[-1,0]
   - U02:%x[0,0]
   - U03:%x[1,0]
   - U04:%x[2,0]
   - U05:%x[-2,0]/%x[-1,0]/%x[0,0]
   - U06:%x[-1,0]/%x[0,0]/%x[1,0]
   - U07:%x[0,0]/%x[1,0]/%x[2,0]
   - U08:%x[-1,0]/%x[0,0]
   - U09:%x[0,0]/%x[1,0]
   - U10:%x[-2,1]/%x[0,1]
   - U11:%x[-2,1]/%x[1,1]
   - U11:%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1]
   - U12:%x[0,0]/%x[0,1]
   - U13:%x[0,1]/%x[1,1]
   - U14:%x[0,1]/%x[2,1]
   - U15:%x[-1,0]/%x[0,1]
   - U16:%x[-1,0]/%x[-1,1]
   - U17:%x[1,0]/%x[1,1]
   - U18:%x[1,0]/%x[1,1]
   - U19:%x[2,0]/%x[2,1]
   - U20:%x[-1,2]
   - U21:%x[-2,2]
   - U22:%x[0,1]/%x[-1,2]
   - U23:%x[0,1]/%x[-2,2]
   - U24:%x[0,0]/%x[-1,2]
   - U25:%x[0,0]/%x[-2,2]
   - U26:%x[-1,2]/%x[-2,2]/%x[0,1]
   - U27:%x[-2,2]/%x[0,1]/%x[1,1]
   - U28:%x[-1,1]/%x[-1,2]/%x[0,1]
   - U29:%x[-1,2]/%x[0,0]/%x[0,1]
7. Boson_train

   - 浙江    ns  B_product_name
   - 在线    b   I_product_name
   - 杭州    ns  I_product_name
   - 4 m   B_time
   - 月 m   I_time
   - 25    m   I_time
   - 日 m   I_time
   - 讯 ng  Out
   - （ x   Out
   - 记者    n   Out
   - x   Out
   - x   B_person_name
   - 施宇翔   nr  I_person_name
   - x   Out
   - 通讯员   n   B_person_name
   - x   Out
   - 方英    nr  B_person_name
   - ） x   Out
   - 毒贩    n   Out
   - 很 zg  Out
   - “ x   Out
   - 时髦    nr  Out
   - ” x   Out
   - ， x   Out
   - 用 p   Out
   - 微信    vn  B_product_name
   - 交易    n   Out
   - 毒品    n   Out
   - 。 x   Out
   - 没 v   Out
   - 料想    v   Out
   - 警方    n   B_person_name
   - 也 d   Out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were debugging in the right direction. The issue is indeed with your template file.

Your training data has 3 columns (column 0:`word`, column 1:`pos-tag` and column 2:`tag`).

You cannot use the `tag` as feature, but your template file has reference to it (i.e, column 2) in many feature definitions (see, U20 to U29). Your training should work after removing/correcting these.

Hope this helps :)

You can also checkout these video tutorials for better understanding of Template Files and Training NER with CRF++ :

1) https://youtu.be/GJHeTvDkIaE

2) https://youtu.be/Ur5umC4BwN4